# send php variable through ajax and return value if successful

Tags: php, ajax

I am doing some processing in a back end page (thread.php) which basically returns values for a time period between dateposted and current time. 
The front end page(index.php) sends a request to thread.php with the value for dateposted. The page thread.php takes in dateposted and returns the values accordingly. index.php would then use the last value of the returned values and sets dateposted as this value which is again sent in as request. So it is a loop. However, I am facing a problem sending the value "dateposted" from index.php to thread.php.

```
    $dateposted = '1328098097623';
<script language="JavaScript">
var dateposted = <?php echo $dateposted ?>;
        function returnValue()
    {
     $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "GET",
                url: "thread.php",
                data: {lastposted : dateposted},
                success: function (html) {
                    if(html)
                    {
                       var newDiv = $('<div/>').html(html);   
                       $('#chatContents').append(newDiv);             
                    }
                }  
            });
    }
</script>
```

This is what i have in thread.php to accept the variable passed over.

```
if(!isset( $lastpost)){
 $lastpost = 0;
 }else{
    $lastpost = $_REQUEST["lastposted"];
    }
```

Basically i have hardcoded "dateposted" for now. I am not sure how to pass in php variables to the another page through ajax. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's happens with the current script? What's the question?

Comment: The data doesnt get sent over. I am not sure if this is the way, i am supposed to send data over ajax to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a quick look that i gave it i suggest you first rap  your php echo Variable with quotes""..

```
var dateposted = <?php echo "$dateposted" ?>;
```

this is to get your javascript syntax correct . Second replace the function(html) to function (data)..because that is the object you wanna send and change your type to POST .Last at your php script change it like this

```
    if(!isset($_POST['lastposted'])){ $lastpost = false; }else{$lastpost=$_POST['lastposted'];}
```

Comment: Wrapping with quotes - indeed. And this syntax error would have been immediately clear if the OP were to use Firefox+Firebug, or Chrome with the Developer bar switched on.

Comment: or you can always add an 'alert("it works");' test in your new function  so you know your javascipt works.

Comment: Cant believe that i overlooked that. Wrapping the text in quotes and changing it to  if(!isset($_GET['lastposted']) made the difference

Comment: Yea your forgot to assign your variable before the if statement.. so that why it was never working.. i changed it to post method because the get method has some limit even in ajax.. its a good habbit to stick with post method

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'echo' the $lastpost at the end of the script being called by ajax (thread.php). You also need to check if isset($_GET['lastpost']) or $_POST['lastpost']. In your case it should be get:

```
if(!isset( $_GET['lastposted'])){
 $lastpost = 0;
 }else{
    $lastpost = $_GET["lastposted"];
    }
echo $lastpost;
```

Your variables also didn't match - check the spelling on the if isset and the assignment.

Comment: Echo shows 0, which means that the variable is not getting passed over.

Comment: I had used Request previously. Doesnt request take in any of these 2?

Comment: Request would take care of both of those, but you weren't checking for request in the if(!isset()) clause.